# Better way to read heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, heroku

I get heroku logs on windows like this in screenshot:
[image]

This is absolutely NIGHTMARE. I can't find a way to make the git bash full screen.

So is there a way I could have a better view of logs or perhaps export to a file?

Answer (score 2):

You have [Heroku addons for logging](https://addons.heroku.com/#logging). Those addons can retain your data for longer period of time and give you access to a nice interface where you can view/search your logs. I used Logentries in one of my projects hosted on Heroku and it is very nice.

[**Logentries**](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) offers a free plan that includes:

1. Send Up to 5 GB per Month
2. Search Duration 7 Days
3. Search check
4. Real-time Alerts check
5. iPhone/Android Notifications

**[FlyData](https://addons.heroku.com/flydata)** offers a free plan that includes:

1. Log Transfer Bandwidth Monthly Limit to Amazon S3 5 GB
2. Heroku Critical Logs and Notification Alerts 30 emails
3. S3 and Redshift Storage on FlyData (For our Sandbox) 1 GB
4. S3 and Redshift Storage Duration on FlyData (For our Sandbox) 30 days
5. Log Transfer Bandwidth Monthly Limit to Amazon Redshift 1 GB
6. Log Transfer Frequency to Amazon Redshift every 5 minutes

[**Papertrail**](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail) offers a free plan that includes:

1. Log volume per day10 MB
2. Search duration2 days
3. Archive duration7 days

Every addon offer many paid plans with a lot of options but I guess the free plan will do it.

Comment: Each of these requires me to add a credit card to heroku, which I haven't added and don't want to add yet.

Comment: From what I remember that is the case if you have more than 5 free apps on Heroku. They won't charge you if you choose only free plans but I understand if you don't want to add a credit card.